# Hadoop Cassandra Wide Row Support

Tags: hadoop, cassandra

When wide_row is set to false in ConfigHelper.setInputColumnFaily, the map method in the mapper class receives a thousand-column chunk per call (one call for each row key) limited by the number set in SlicePredicate.
However, when wide_row is set to true, the map method in the mapper class receives one column per call (each row key can have as many calls as the number of colu) and ignores the SlidePredicate.

http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.1/cluster_architecture/hadoop_integration
The link on datastax seems to indicate that it should still output thousand-column chunks (assume that number is set in SlicePredicate), so is this a bug or is there something I am missing?

I am using 1.1.2 Hadoop and 1.2.4 Cassandra

Thanks

Comment: Have you had any luck with this? Im finding the exact same behaviour in Cassandra 1.2.6, where the InputSlicePredicate seems to be ignored for wide rows.